# Convert a string of wei to a string of Ether

Tags: ethers.js

How can I convert a string value: "583973287398480127359.637419834668637206", which is in wei to ether?

```
ethers.utils.formatEther(ethers.utils.parseUnits("583973287398480127359.637419834668637206", 18))
```

Currently this gives me the same value, but I'm looking to get `583.973...`

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options to convert Wei to Ether.

You can use `ethers.utils.formatEther(WEI_VALUE)` with ethers.js V5, or `ethers.formatEther(WEI_VALUE)` with ethers.js V6.

> Note that your Wei value has a decimal pointer in it; it's not supposed to be like that, as Wei values exist to allow more precise transactions and to handle fractional amounts of Ether.

Here are some examples with your value:

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');

// ethers.js V5
// Convert Wei to Ether
const weiAmount = '583973287398480127359'; 
const etherAmount = ethers.utils.formatEther(weiAmount);
console.log(`Wei to Ether: ${etherAmount}`); 

// ethers.js V6
// Convert Wei to Ether
const weiAmount = '583973287398480127359'; 
const etherAmount = ethers.formatEther(weiAmount)
console.log(`Wei to Ether: ${etherAmount}`);
```

This will return this:

```sh
Wei to Ether: 583.973287398480127359
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ethValue = Number("583973287398480127359.637419834668637206") / (10 ** 18)
const stringValue = String(ethValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The value cannot be in wei.** Wei is the smallest unit on ethereum. You cannot have fractions of the smallest unit, otherwise it wouldn't be the smallest unit anymore.

In your statement you tell the `parseUnits()` function that you give it `ether` (because `ether` has 18 decimals). And in the `formatEther()` function you tell ethers.js to convert the `ether` value to ether, which **is** the same value.

##### Take a good look at the [docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/display-logic/) they explain currency conversion extremely well.

There you will also find that: `parseEther(...)` === `parseUnits(..., 18)`
So currently you are converting your number to ether twice. I would suggest for readabiliy that you supply the unit name as a string rather than the decimal places.

Last but not least here is some sample code:

```js
// If you want to keep your syntax
ethers.utils.formatEther(ethers.utils.parseUnits("583973287398480127359", 0))

// Or if you like it more simple
ethers.utils.formatEther("583973287398480127359", "wei")
```

In a nutshell:

1. Wei doesn't have any decimal places (you could round to get rid of them)
2. You can supply the name of the unit rather than their decimal places (0 = `wei`, ..., 15 = `finney`, 18 = `ether`) *(table below for reference)*
3. `formatEther()` and `parseEther` are just convenience functions for `parseUnit` and `formatUnit`
4. Internally (on ethereum), all values are represented as `uint256`.

| Name | Decimals |
| --- | --- |
| wei | 0 |
| kwei | 3 |
| mwei | 6 |
| gwei | 9 |
| szabo | 12 |
| finney | 15 |
| ether | 18 |